# String separated by space in value field breaking when entered as a variable

Tags: php, html, textbox

I have a variable called $value in php which has a string value. When I echo this $value, I can see the entire string. However, when I pass it in the value field in html textbox, I can only see the first word of the string. Following is the code:-

```
$check = '<input type="checkbox" name="transcript'.$i.'" value=0 '.$checked.' />';
$value = $DB->get_field('course_completions', 'REMARKS', array ('course'=>$course->id, 'userid'=>$this->user->id), $strictness=IGNORE_MISSING);
$remark = '<input type="text" name="remark'.$i.'" value ='.$value.' size="30"/>';
```

Example:->
if $value is a string called "First comment", I can only see "First" in the textbox in html and the html code that gets generates looks like:-

```
<input type="text" name="remark1" value="First" comment="" size="30">
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Quote the attribute in HTML  Also, call `htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES)` on it.  `value ="'.htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES).'"...`  You should _always_ quote your HTML attributes.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - this is the answer isn't it? Post as answer and I'll delete mine...

Comment: @Robbie You can have it. I'm looking for a duplicate b/c this gets asked often.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only first word In a multi word variable is being displayed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805535/only-first-word-in-a-multi-word-variable-is-being-displayed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 $remark = '<input type="text" name="remark'.$i.'" value ='.$value.' size="30"/>';
```

to

```
$remark = '<input type="text" name="remark'.$i.'" value ="'.htmlspecialchars($value).'" size="30"/>';
```

Comment: use `htmlentities()` with `ENT_QUOTES` because it will encode both single & double

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski why would single quotes need to be escaped?

Comment: @Jack In this exact case they don't but in general usage, it is a good habit because you may be quoting attrs with single or double and needn't worry about whether you need ENT_QUOTES or ENT_NOQUOTES for `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I guess good practice for a "newbie" is htmlentities(), so would have been best advice, yes. I avoid as it makes everything longer, harder to read and I'm always consistent with my output, so never need it. Hopefuly OP will read comments and do the right thing.

Comment: Thank You. Tried both htmlspecialchars() and htmlentities() and both work. Reading up the differences between them now.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:

```
$remark = '<input type="text" name="remark'.$i.'" value ="'.$value.'" size="30"/>';
```