# PHP only displaying first word of string in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm dynamically creating a table from a MySQL query.  For some reason, the 'notes' field below is only returning the first word of the string, although when I test it with `echo($notes)` it shows up just fine.  `$status` is similarly set, and also is fine.  What am I missing?  I assume it has something to do with prepopulating the text field with the value.  I'm using codeigniter.

```
$notes = empty($row["notes"]) ? "None" : $row["notes"];
    echo($notes);
    echo('
    <tr class="even">
        <td class="status-icons">'.$error_level.'</td>
        <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
        <td>'.$status.'</td>
        <td class="notes-col">
          <input type="text" name="submit_notes" value='.$notes.' class="notes-copy">
        </td>
    </tr>'
```

Comment: Probably not related, but echo is not a function, the correct way is 'echo $notes;'

Comment: Good to know, but that's just there for debugging.  Is there a difference, or is that just a standard?

Comment: [according to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) it can be used as a function but will not always work like it.

Comment: @thumbtackthief, just a standard used to differentiate functions from language constructs.  echo is not a function in php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only first word In a multi word variable is being displayed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805535/only-first-word-in-a-multi-word-variable-is-being-displayed)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

replace this

```
   value='.$notes.'
```

with

```
    value="'.$notes.'"
```

the double quotes are for the `Value` because it originally has two quotes like: `value=""`

Comment: always the little things :) like a space before the opening php tag -_-

Comment: @MarkBasmayor sorry i didnt mean to beat you to it :), if i knew you will post it i should let you :) .

Comment: should probably urlencode the value as well or a stray ' is going to blow it up.

Comment: @Orangepill I'm using codeigniter and django--isn't that automatic?  I tested some values with quotes and didn't seem to have a problem.