# Will only display first part of mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, fetch

Although variations of this question have been asked before, none of them have helped me solve this puzzle. at present the form I have put together updates the database fine etc, the issue is when I go to edit the field, only the first part of the data is shown for example, if the data was 'Sunny Day' then when i clicked to edit this field all i would get is 'Sunny', so then if i then clicked update, it would edit the database back to Sunny. Am i missing something?!

Thanks in advance.

```
    // Connects to your Database
    $query=mysql_connect("localhost", "cl52-abcdef","abcdef") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("cl52-abcdef",$query);
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
      $id=$_GET['id'];
      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
        $holdesc1=$_POST['holdesc1'];
        $holdest1=$_POST['holdest1'];
        $rrp1=$_POST['rrp1'];
        $cpe1=$_POST['cpe1'];
        $ea1=$_POST['ea1'];

        $query3=mysql_query("update DealOne set holdesc1='$holdesc1',holdest1='$holdest1',rrp1='$rrp1',cpe1='$cpe1',ea1='$ea1' where id='$id'");
        if($query3)
        {
          header('location:list.php');
        }
      }
      $query1=mysql_query("select holdesc1, holdest1, rrp1, cpe1, ea1 from DealOne where id='$id'");
      $query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
      ?>
        <form method="post" action="">
        1 <input type="text" value=<? echo $query2['holdesc1']; ?> name="holdesc1"><br>
        2 <input type="text" value=<? echo $query2['holdest1']; ?> name="holdest1"><br>
        3 <input type="text" value=<? echo $query2['rrp1']; ?> name="rrp1"><br>
        4 <input type="text" value=<? echo $query2['cpe1']; ?> name="cpe1"><br>
        5 <input type="text" value=<? echo $query2['ea1']; ?> name="ea1"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update" />
        </form>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `mysql_query` has been deprecated for a while now.  Switch to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Yes - you're missing quotes in your `value` attributes. You must quote them as `value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($query2[...], ENT_QUOTES); ?>"` View your browser's page source and you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: Are you saying that your data is always truncated before the first space?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only first word In a multi word variable is being displayed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805535/only-first-word-in-a-multi-word-variable-is-being-displayed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the first part of the data is showing up because your `value` attribute values do not have quotes around it. Otherwise, your HTML looks like: `<input type="text" value=Sunny day name="holdesc1">`

Change your text inputs to the following:

```
<input type="text" value="<? echo $query2['holdesc1']; ?>" name="holdesc1"><br>
<input type="text" value="<? echo $query2['holdest1']; ?>" name="holdest1"><br>
<input type="text" value="<? echo $query2['rrp1']; ?>" name="rrp1"><br>
<input type="text" value="<? echo $query2['cpe1']; ?>" name="cpe1"><br>
<input type="text" value="<? echo $query2['ea1']; ?>" name="ea1"><br><br>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, so simple, but just couldnt get it!, ta